# Javascript object constructor function arguments

Tags: javascript

Can I have a variable in a constructor fuction without having it in the function argument?

like this below:

```
function Person(name,height,weight){
this.name=name;
this.height=height;
this.weight=weight;
this.bmi=null;
this.calculateBMI = function()
{
    if (this.bmi===null){
        this.bmi = this.weight / (Math.pow(this.height,2));
    }
    return this.bmi;
}
}
var person1 = new Person("alayna",23, 56)
```

can I have function Person(name, height, weight), and inside it I have this.bmi? how does the function know what is bmi here?

Comment: Yes you can have other function scoped variables as well, ie defined with `var`,`let`,`const` etc there is nothing that limits variable use/definition in constructor functions

Comment: There's nothing special about constructors except that they're called automatically when you use `new`. A constructor can do anything to the object that any other method can.

Comment: Are you asking if you can do `var bmi = null; this.calculateBMI = function() { if (bmi===null)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose whether to use the value of a parameter or not

```js
function Person (name, height, weight) {
  this.name = name;
  this.height = height;
  this.weight = weight;
  this.bmi = this.weight / (Math.pow(this.height, 2));
}

Person.prototype.calculateBMI = function() {
  this.bmi = this.weight / (Math.pow(this.height, 2));
  return this.bmi;
}

var person1 = new Person("alayna",23, 56);
```

Although, perhaps you want to look at getters and setters:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Which will allow you to update `bmi` every time `height` or `weight` is updated. For example the following will update the `bmi` if either `height` or `weight` ever changes

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, height, weight) {
    this.name = name;
    this._height = height;
    this._weight = weight;
    this.bmi = this._weight / (Math.pow(this._height, 2));
  }
  
  get weight() {
    return this._weight;
  }
  
  set weight(value) {
    this._weight = value;
    this.bmi = value / (Math.pow(this._height, 2));
  }
  
  get height() {
    return this._height;
  }
  
  set height(value) {
    this._height = value;
    this.bmi = this._weight / (Math.pow(value, 2));
  }
}

const person1 = new Person('alayna', 23, 56);
console.log(person1.bmi);
person1.height = 25;
console.log(person1.bmi);
```

Comment: My question is the other way round. If i don’t have 'bmi' in the function argument, like Person (name, height, weight), can I have this.bmi inside the function?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer to remove `bmi` from params